# Maven - use assembly file and configuration from the parent project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a parent project that defines the entire configuration for the assembly plugin including the assembly.xml file (creates a tar.gz). Now I want to have multiple children that can use the parent's project configuration and the parent's assembly file.

Now I tried different scenarios and the configuration works fine but I get the error that assembly file is not to be found locally. What I want to achieve is not having to configure and add the same file over and over again in all the projects. Is there a way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Defining the confiugration etc of maven-assembly-plugin in a parent does not makes sense except it is defined in a pluginManagement block.

Comment: @khmarbaise ok, so I should use pluginManagement to define behaviour? I mean, what I want to achieve is not having to configure and add the same file over and over again in all the projects

Comment: It would be helpfull if you could post your full pom file or an example of it which is not working as you expect it...

Answer (score 1):

You should disable assembly in all sub-module's pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <skipAssembly>true</skipAssembly>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

And more often, it's recommend to create a dedicated sub-module to config assemble plugin rather than config assembly plugin in parent pom.xml

Comment: Can you expand please on the second choice? (use dedicated submodule for assembly)

Comment: Also if I use skipAssembly then the expected tar file doesn't get created anymore

Comment: NOTE: not add the <skipAssembly/> on your existing parent pom.xml! you should insert the given config to all your SUB-MODULES' pom.xml

Comment: yes, this is what I did. I get `Assemblies have been skipped per configuration of the skipAssembly parameter` and if I want to install I get that the expected tar file doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

I use the maven-remote-resources-plugin to share assembly descriptors.  First, create a separate project that holds the assembly descriptors you want to share.

```
project-assemblies
  src
    main
      resources
        <your assembly descriptors, in any package structure you like>
  pom.xml
```

The POM's build section (assume this is project com.mycompany.project:project-assemblies):

```
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>bundle</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <includes>
                  <include>**/*.xml</include>
              </includes>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

To reference this from another project you add this to the project's POM:

```
<properties>
  <shared.assemblies.dir>${project.build.directory}/assemblies</shared.assemblies.dir>
  <project-assemblies.version><yourAssemblyProjectVersion</project-assemblies.version>
</properties>

<!-- copy the assembly descriptors into this project -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>assemblies</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <resourceBundles>
          <resourceBundle>com.mycompany.project:project-assemblies:${project-assembly.version}</resourceBundle>
        </resourceBundles>
        <attached>false</attached>
        <outputDirectory>${shared.assemblies.dir}</outputDirectory>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Setting attached to false means the contents of the bundle won't be included in the final project build.

```
<!-- Apply the retrieved assembly descriptor to this project -->
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>run-assembly</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>${shared.assemblies.dir}/<pathToAssemblyDescriptor></descriptor>
        </descriptors>
        <!-- other config here -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: There is no need for maven-remote-resources-plugin to share descriptors this can be done without just [read the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/sharing-descriptors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, create a dedicated sub-module to config assemble plugin rather than config assembly plugin in parent pom.xml

as for sample, please refer to: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html

In this sample, it creates an sub-module called: distribution

This is an good example for you! Good luck!